# 8085 programming the ani instruction

Tags: 8085

Why is the AC flag set while using the `ANI` instruction in 8085:

```
MVI A, A3H
ANI 97H
HLT
```

The sign flag is set which is understandable but the AC flag is also set which makes no sense because, there's no carry from the **D3** bit to **D4** bit. How is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANI` *unconditionally* sets `AC`. That's how it's defined.

> ANI [...] [...] AC is set.

Comment: no reason then?

Comment: Most likely the reason has to do with decoding the instruction. It probably happened to fit where other instructions unconditionally set AC so it was easier to just roll with it.